# How can I get the server name for where node.js is running?

Tags: node.js

I want to add a line that will point to a different database depending on the server I am running node.js on (localhost vs test.com, etc).  How do I get the server name in node.js?  That is, what is the server side equivalent to location.host?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var os = require('os');
os.hostname();
```

[link](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html)

Comment: Thank you.  Simple question that I couldn't find the answer for.

Comment: This will give the machine's name, not the server full qualified domain name.

Answer (score 1):

```
req.headers.host #The request host.
```

You can refer to Node.js document [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_host).