# How to get current nameservers of o.s. from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, nameservers

From bash get the current nameserver using:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

But, how to get nameservers from O.S. using nodejs 10 in cross platform? (windows, mac, linux, etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the server name for where node.js is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324247/how-can-i-get-the-server-name-for-where-node-js-is-running)

Comment: Nameserver is not server name, NS (NameServer) is the DNS service address

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to node.js, but the following commands will do. If you exec the command then the stdout processing could be moved in node.

Mac

```
scutil --dns | grep 'nameserver\[[0-9]*\]'
```

Windows

```
ipconfig /all | findstr /R "DNS\ Servers"
```

Linux systemd

```
systemd-resolve --status | grep "DNS Servers"
```

Linux fallback

```
grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
```